# Checking if port is used by a stream

Tags: php, sockets, stream, udp

I'm not quite certain if You understand what I mean by the title so I will try to be a bit more detailed.

I'm using `stream_socket_server` in order to recieve packets through it. Unfortunately, at the same time I might have a few more scripts doing the same job but naturally, every script needs to have different port. My question is, how to check if a port is used by a stream? I tried several scripts but none of them work. Any ideas?

An example:

```
stream_socket_server("udp://0.0.0.0:$port", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND)
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Before creating stream server, you can create stream client and try to connect that port like;

```
$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://0.0.0.0:$port", $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "Port is not used";
    stream_socket_server("udp://0.0.0.0:$port", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND);
}
```

Comment: The error I'm getting now is: "Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://0.0.0.0:33334 (The requested address is not valid in its context. )"

Comment: Use a valid IP address.

Comment: tried but it does not work. I even tried changing tcp to udp and my public ip, apache server ip and my local ip. None works